# How to suppress DEVENV launching help window on error

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer, build-process

DEVENV.exe command I am using to create build.In case solution file has issues and not properly linked to setup project .It throws error "Invalid project " error.Then it opens DEVENV.exe 's switch -help window .

```
"%dotNet2010%\devenv.exe"  MyApp.sln /build "Release"  /project "MayApp\Setup.vdproj" /Out "%LOGLOCATION%"
```

I guess ,This is causing long wait during automatic run and the log file not updated completely.

Any idea ,How to stop this help windows during errors?

[image]

Comment: You should use `MSBuild` look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119498/building-a-solution-file-using-msbuild

Comment: DEVENV has more options than MSBuild it seems. Also My deployments involves installer projects too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980836/what-is-the-difference-between-using-devenv-and-msbuild-in-cruisecontrol-net-bui I am trying to understanding why devenv launching help window ? Are there any control parameteres?

Answer (score 0):

As per the below link There is a known issue with DEVENV 2010 command.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/724272/devenv-hanging-on-cmd-line

To fix - We need to upgrade to VS2012  or hot fix need to be applied.

The hang is not happening always.
But with VS2012 devenv command - No hang and error is logged properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress all GUI windows and instead have all output redirected to the console then use **DEVENV.COM** instead of devenv.exe. Note the **.COM** extension.

For build related tasks it is recommended that you use MSBuild see [MSDN Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.100).aspx).

Here is an example of using MSBuild to build Deployment or Setup projects. 
[Building Visual Studio Deployment Projects With MSBuild](http://gavindraper.com/2012/02/17/building-visual-studio-deployment-projects-with-msbuild/)

In either case ensure your call is to DEVENV.COM instead of DEVENV.EXE.